# Is that possible map an image with curves?

Tags: jquery, imagemap

I know that to mapping an image we have 3 tips of hotspot:
   1. Rectangle hostpot
   2. Circle hotspot
   3. Polygon hotspot (using only lines)

What I am trying to do is mapping a curved image, like this:

[image]

I need to do jquery mapster on wings and in the hand, curved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinoin your best option is to trace the guidelines using a polygon.. There are a lot of free tools on the internet that will help you do this visually. I recomment using [this one](https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/media/uploads/demos/s/u/summerstyle/365ccfd644f2b008c33f0046d2ba1a8f/summer-html-image-ma_1355318513_demo_package/index.html).

Comment: Yeah, tracing polygon results in lot of points, html text, spent more time, but yeah I presume that is the only way :(

Comment: @FranciscoCarvalho Using the link in my answer it can be done in 2 mins